# How to get the relative path from Symfony's Router

Tags: symfony, url, routes

Symfony's `UrlGeneratorInterface` can generate absolute paths for routes, e.g: `'path/to/web/app.php/my/path'`, but I need the relative path i.e: `'/my/path'`, this can be done for the current matched route using `Request::getPathInfo`, how can it be done for other routes (besides taking the base path from the request, and trimming the returned value from `UrlGeneratorInterface` with that)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it wouldn't be possible any other way than:

- trimming you mentioned,
- setting PATH_INFO environment variable accordingly.

I suggest reconfiguring your httpd to remove `web/app.php` from request path - it would be more portable.